# Cointegration tests and deciding which is Y and X variables

Tags: time-series, cointegration, ardl

I understand the Engle-Granger test, we regress Y on X, get residuals, then test those residuals for cointegration.

What does it mean to do the other way round, I.e to get residuals from
X = c + bY

Instead of
Y = c + bX

Should these results be different?

I could ask the same about the ARDL test: should the results on the presence of a long run relationship differ from the bounds test differ depending on what is specified as the regressors or regressand? If not, what does the difference in results mean?

Many thanks!

Comment: yes, you won't get the same results. I guess you can view it as a problem with the EG test. I would try both ways and see if you get similar results. It stems from the fact that the regression model is not symmetric in the sense that regressing y on x is not the inverse of regressing x on y.

Comment: Thank you for your response. That is fair. But i observe the same issues when using the ARDL bounds test - which impacts on conclusion. Where theory does not specify the type of regression to run i.e all that matters is establishing presence of cointegration, what would be the best methods to use?

Comment: yes, I'm not familiar with the bounds test but the ARDL would also have the same problem of lack of symmetry. I don't think a test that is symmetric exists ? I've never used it but it's likely that johansen's cointegration framework is also not symmetric. I think the only to do is do it both ways and see if you observe a contradiction.  Maybe someone here can chime in and offer some kins of solution because I don't know of one.